# if ajax status return true then change table row status like yes or no

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to change table row status (Yes or No) when ajax return true. my ajax request working fine but have changed table all row status.

here is my view

```
@foreach($order_details as $key => $list)

  <tr>
     <td>{{$list->order_product_name}}</td>
     <td>{{ $size }}</td>
     <td>{{ $color }}</td>
     <td>{{$list->order_product_quantity}}</td>
     <td>{{ $list->tax_rate_percentage }}</td>
     <td>{{ $list->tax_amount }}</td>
     <td>{{ $list->order_product_unit_price }}</td>
     <td>{{ $list->order_product_total_price }}</td>
     <td><input type="text" data-order-id="{{ $list->order_id }}" class="product-check-physical"  name="product_id">
     </td>
     <td>
         <span class="done label label-success">Yes</span>
         <span class="not-done label label-danger">No</span>
     </td>
```

@endforeach

here is my ajax code

```
        var site_url = $('.site_url').val();
        $('.done').hide();
        $('.not-done').show();
        $('.product-check-physical').on('keyup', function () {
            var order_id = $(this).data('order-id')
            var product_id = $('.product-check-physical').val();
            $.ajax({
                url : site_url + '/order/details/product/issue/delivery/man/' + order_id + '/' + product_id,
                type : 'GET',
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data) {
                    if(data.status == 0) {
                        sweetAlert('Sorry....','This product not found','error');

                        return;
                    }
                    //alert(data.status.order_product_name )
                    $('.done').show().closest('tr');
                    $('.not-done').hide().closest('tr');

                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        });
```

here is my controller

```
$product =\DB::table('order_details')
        ->where('order_id',$order_id)
        ->where('order_product_id',$product_id)
        ->first();
    if(!$product) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 0]);
    }
    return response()->json(['status' => $product]);
```

Comment: well, `$('.done').show().closest('tr')` will cause **ALL** elements with class including `done` to be shown ... the `.closest('tr')` at the end of that will do **nothing** - similarly for the `$('.not-done').hide().closest('tr')`, will hide all elements with class that includes `not-done`

Comment: i have try remove ....closest('tr') but it is not working. i want only check that row which are chcked

Comment: Removing isn't the answer. You need to figure out how jQuery works

Comment: thanks brother, i know this problem is when ajax return true or false  it effected all ...done or ...not-done class due to same name of the table row where i called  i can not figure out how way i put different css class in each row

Comment: you don't need to do that ... the `this` in the `on('keyup', function () {` callback will refer to which `.product-check-physical` has the keybaord focus, therefore, knowing which input you are in, you can rewrite the code to change the appropriate `.done`/`.not-done` spans